# Sum a collection of objects which contain numeric properties only with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an object model like this:

```
public class Quantity
{
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Volume { get; set; }
    // perhaps more decimals...

    public static Quantity operator +(Quantity quantity1, Quantity quantity2)
    {
        return new Quantity()
        {
            Weight = quantity1.Weight + quantity2.Weight,
            Volume = quantity1.Volume + quantity2.Volume
        };
    }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public Quantity Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public IEnumerable<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to introduce a readonly property `TotalQuantity` on the `Order` class which should sum up the quantities of all OrderDetails.

I am wondering if there is better "LINQ way" than this:

```
public class Order
{
    // ...
    public Quantity TotalQuantity
    {
        get
        {
            Quantity totalQuantity = new Quantity();
            if (OrderDetails != null)
            {
                totalQuantity.Weight =
                    OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.Quantity.Weight);
                totalQuantity.Volume =
                    OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.Quantity.Volume);
            }
            return totalQuantity;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not a nice solution as it iterates twice through the OrderDetails. And something like this is not supported (even though a + operator is provided in the Quantity class):

```
Quantity totalQuantity = OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.Quantity); // doesn't compile
```

Is there a better way to build the total sum in LINQ?

(Just for theoretical interest, a simple foreach loop would also do its job well of course.)

Thanks for feedback!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
OrderDetails.Select(o => o.Quantity).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y)
```

If you'd prefer not to have the overhead of the new Quantity object for each addition (RE comment), you could use something like:

```
new Quantity {
    Weight = OrderDetails.Select(o => o.Quantity.Weight).Sum(),
    Volume = OrderDetails.Select(o => o.Quantity.Volume).Sum()
};
```

Not as nice as the first one, and slightly more awkward (and slower?) than just the plain `foreach` loop.

You can find more about the `Aggregate()` method [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx).

Comment: In that case you don't need WhateverProperty, since TotalQuantity returns a Quantity

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks. Made a flurry of edits as I kept re-interpreting the question; settled on this one, and didn't think to take that out. :)

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks! I was just thinking a second time about my remark that my solution in the question is not a "nice solution". It only creates one single `Quantity` object and then adds up decimals twice to build the total sum while using the + overload creates a new Quantity object for each binary addition. I'm not sure what's better performance-wise, although using the + operator makes the code looking more friendly. But that's another question.

Comment: @Slauma: Thanks. For a compromise between the two, see the new edit.