# Collection<T>.Sum(a => a.ushortProperty) to ulong

Tags: c#, sum

```
public class Foo
{
    public ushort Weight { get; }
}
```

```
public class Bar<T> : IEnumerable where T : Foo
{
    private Collection<T> _contents;
    ...
    public ulong TotalWeight { get { return _contents.Sum(a => a.Weight); } }
}
```

I'm expecting the total to add up to more than the maximum value of a ushort.

I'm getting an Intellisense error: "Ambiguous Invocation", with a list of numeric types that doesn't include ushort or ulong. I'm not sure what it wants.

I also tried using Select (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612938/sum-a-collection-of-objects-which-contain-numeric-properties-only-with-linq)), as follows:

```
_contents.Select(a => a.Weight).Sum()
```

but Intellisense complains that it cannot resolve the Sum method and lists a bunch of candidates that also does not include ushort or ulong. Again, I'm not sure what it wants.

I apologize if this is really newbish, I just don't understand what Intellisense is telling me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) overload which applies to a `ushort` sequence or to a general sequence and a projection to `ushort`. The simplest approach would be to simply cast to `long`:

```
return _contents.Sum(a => (long) a.Weight);
```

This will alleviate the overflow problem as well. Note that there is no overload using `ulong` either. If you have enough `ushort` values to overflow `long`, it's probably going to take a while to add them up anyway :)

Comment: Thanks! This works if I cast the whole affair to ulong: (ulong)_contents.Sum(a => (long) a.Weight);

Comment: @Superstringcheese: Yup, that should be fine.